# How to start working with Bluetooth 4.0?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am interested in Bluetooth 4.0. Where to start adventure with it? If you have any materials, links, books I'll be very grateful. If you could share this knowledge. I would to use BT 4.0 to connect a PC (no matter what system) with a smart phone (eg. Windows Phone).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right, I tried to quickly put together some relevant information that might help you. There is a big chance I have missed thing because this is a broad topic.
I am pretty sure you will find help here when you will have more specific questions.

Basically when it comes to Bluetooth (Smart, 4.0) devices and programming / connecting to them we can talk about two things:

Bluetooh **Clients** and **Servers**

### Servers:

usually provide some data to *clients*. Think about a Heart rate monitor that captures someones heartrate and "stream" it so anyone who connects to the server will be able to read the data.

### Clients:

On the other hand clients connect to servers (how obvious) to collect their data, or in some cases to write to them.

### Bluetooth Profiles

Bluetooth devices (servers) have so called **GATT** (generic attribute) **Profiles**. These profiles describe a kind of unique set of **Services**. Each **Service** has different **Characteristics**. These **characteristics** hold the actual values.

Think about a *Heart rate monitor* (HRM). Thats a server. It measures heart rate so clients that connect to it can read / collect it's data. Heart rate monitors have a specific **Heart rate monitor GATT profile** which describes **services** and inside the **services** there are the heart rate specific **characteristics** like: **heart rate measurement**, **body sensor location**, etc.
When a client wants to read these values it has to connect to the HRM, discover it's services and characteristics, then read the values from the discovered characteristics.

### Async

It might be obvious but Bluetooth programming (implementing server / client connection and data transfer) is *async*. It means the client sends something then waits till the server answers then can the it progress to the next step.
Your whole software has to be implemented keeping **async programming design** in mind.

### Documentation

I have to say I found the **iOS** documentation and support very useful when I developed my first bluetooth app.**Android** was somewhat more difficult for me because of the lack of examples I found. Also general bluetooth 4.0 support only became available since Android 4.3. *(different bluetooth chip manufacturers in different Android phones had different low level bluetooth stack so to use them one had to write native bluetooth code for each different chip with their own SDK - prior to Android 4.3)*

#### Bluetooth.org

I would suggest to start with this:

- https://developer.bluetooth.org/DevelopmentResources/Pages/Quick-Start-Kit.aspx
- https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/Technology-Overview.aspx
- https://developer.bluetooth.org/DevelopmentResources/Pages/default.aspx
- https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/Pages/default.aspx

#### iOS

It won't hurt if you read about `Core-bluetooth` framework, which is the iOS approach even if you don't plan to develop on iOS. Since it is well documented it might give you a better overall understanding:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html

#### Android

Same for android:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

#### Windows 8

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207007%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've found "Bluetooth Low Energy: The Developer's Handbook" by Robin Heydon very useful.  It deals with all the little details so you can understand how things are working on the lower level.

As a reference, I've found the Bluetooth specification PDF very useful (though it's sometimes hard to find what you need).  It looks like they just released a 4.1 version here:  https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/adopted-specifications

EDIT:  both references aren't specific to any particular implementation, so I'm not sure how much they'd help if you wanted to learn something specific like iOS BLE or Android BLE.